# Lipids that are not found in human body

Tags: fat-metabolism, lipids, fatty-acid-synthase

I know that human body contains FA some of which are essential and the other is not depending on the ability of the body to synthesize them in a sufficient amount, but I need a reference of the lipids types that are found at animals, plants, insects, microorganisms,....etc but not in the human body.